# RavenDB Map/Reduce with grouping by date

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have to create a query to get a statistic by post per  year/month, e.g. group by date. I created an index:

```
public class Posts_Count : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post, ArchiveItem>
{
    public Posts_Count()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
              select new
                         {
                             Year = post.PublishedOn.Year,
                             Month = post.PublishedOn.Month,
                             Count = 1
                         };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new {
                                 result.Year,
                                 result.Month
                            }
                            into agg
                            select new
                                       {                                               
                                           Year = agg.Key.Year,
                                           Month = agg.Key.Month,
                                           Count = agg.Sum(x => x.Count)
                                       };
    }
}
```

In studio I have next map and reduce functions:

Map:

```
docs.Posts.Select(post => new {Year = post.PublishedOn.Year, Month = post.PublishedOn.Month, Count = 1})
```

Reduce:

```
results
.GroupBy(result => new {Year = result.Year, Month = result.Month})
.Select(agg => new {Year = agg.Key.Year, Month = agg.Key.Month, Count = agg.Sum(x => ((System.Int32)(x.Count)))})
```

But the problem is I alway get a null values of Year and Month properties:

```
{
   "Year": null,
   "Month": null,
   "Count": "1"
}
```

Can anybody help me to resolve the issue with my code? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  I tested it and it works in the current unstable build 1.2.2096.  There have been some discussion around this lately on the RavenDB google group, so perhaps it was broken previously.  Try again with the current build and see if it works for you now.

Comment: hmm, the above index looks fine but shouldn't we need to define the SortOption for the each item? such as `Sort(x => x.Year, SortOptions.Int); Sort(x => x.Month, SortOptions.Int); Sort(x => x.Count, SortOptions.Int);`? Otherwise, wouldn't we get inconsistently sorted result?